# Import Database (.mdf) file built in visual studio 08 into Visual Studio 12

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have worked on visual studio 08 as an undergrad and i want to start developing my then project in visual studio 12 . How can i do that ... There is no option to import .mdf files.

any help will be appreaciated.

I got the answer to the above question , i connected the data base , but how ever its gives me an error when i run the code .

I am trying to make a web application in visual basic .

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Conn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim password As String
        password = Encrypt(TextBox2.Text, "&%#@?,:*")
        'Queries
        Dim query As String = "select * from Registration where username='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and password='" & password & "'"
        Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection(Conn)
        Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand(query, SQLConn)
        SQLConn.Open()

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader
        dr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader()
        dr.Read()
        ' If Present in databse it will enter here
        If dr.HasRows Then

            ' Remember Session
            'Session("viewid") = dr("userid")
            Session("userid") = dr("userid")
            Session("username") = dr("username")
            Session("email") = dr("email")
            'Remember Me on this pc
            If CheckBox1.Checked Then
                Response.Cookies("UserName").Value = dr("username")
                Response.Cookies("UserName").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1)
            End If
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx")
        End If
        SQLConn.Close()
        Label4.Text = "* Incorrect Username/ Password/ Mode. Re-enter!"
    End Sub
```

It gives me an error at SQLConn.Open():

SqlException was unhandled by user code

The user instance login flag is not allowed when connecting to a user instance of SQL Server. The connection will be closed.

Can someone tell me what need to be done ?

Comment: You'll need to document the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you try to attach your DB file on SQL Server? There was a similar problem under Windows 7, which was cause by invalid security rights when installing SQL.

The workaround was to delete a directory, which is automatically recreated if missing:
 Delete C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS.

But I really don't know if it is the same cause on Win8.

Hope this helps
Serge